# count total number of records from 2 date fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently counting the number of records by date and displaying the total on a calendar as a clickable event.

[image]

I now need to count the total number of records by 2 date fields:

`Delivery Date + Estimated Delivery Date = X`

This is my current code for 1 delivery date:

```
$query = "SELECT 
count(DISTINCT company_entity) as company, 
deliverydate as ShipDate 
FROM myorders 
WHERE 
deliverydate >= '$current_date'
GROUP BY deliverydate";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $the_number_of_deliveries_on_this_date = $row ["company"];
    $ShipDate                              = $row ["ShipDate"];

    $arr [] = array (
      'title' => $the_number_of_deliveries_on_this_date." (Deliveries)",
      'url' => 'list_of_orders_by_date.php?dt=' . substr ( $ShipDate, 0, 10 ),
      'start' => substr ( $ShipDate, 0, 10 )
    );
  }
  echo json_encode ( $arr );
  $result->free();
}
```

Here's my attempt to count from 2 delivery date fields:

```
$query = "SELECT 
count(DISTINCT company_entity) as company, 
deliverydate as ShipDate
FROM myorders 
WHERE 
deliverydate >= '$current_date'
GROUP BY deliverydate
UNION
SELECT 
count(DISTINCT company_entity) as company2, 
deliverydate2 as ShipDate2
FROM myorders 
WHERE 
deliverydate2 >= '$current_date'
GROUP BY deliverydate2
";
```

This is what i get:

[image]

The query counts from both records and I get 2 results but I don't want 2. I want the total of both.

`Delivery Date + Delivery Date2 = X`

I also tried:

```
$query = "SELECT 
COUNT(*) as all_of_them
count(DISTINCT company_entity) as company, 
deliverydate as ShipDate
FROM myorders 
WHERE 
deliverydate >= '$current_date'
GROUP BY deliverydate
UNION
SELECT 
count(DISTINCT company_entity) as company2, 
deliverydate2 as ShipDate2
FROM myorders 
WHERE 
deliverydate2 >= '$current_date'
GROUP BY deliverydate2
";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add in a sum to your count function as long as you are returning all the results.

```
$query = "SELECT 
sum(COUNT(*)) as all_of_them
count(DISTINCT company_entity) as company, 
deliverydate as ShipDate
FROM myorders 
WHERE 
deliverydate >= '$current_date'
GROUP BY deliverydate
```

Count will return the number of records.
If you want the sum of them, then write a query to return the two rows you want, group them by something then add in the sum function to get the combined result. You'll need to take out the count for that

Comment: thats only counting where the deliverydate>='$current_date' i also need where the deliverydate2>='$current_date' If i add a OR clause, i get 0 results

Comment: I don't understand why you are unioning two different selects from the same table. Just use one join that returns all the results from the table

Comment: I get no results with this query - $query = "SELECT 
count(DISTINCT nextgenorder_company_entity) as company, 
nextgenorder_deliverydate as ShipDate,
nextgenorder_deliverydate2 as ShipDate2
FROM nextgenorders2 
WHERE 
(nextgenorder_deliverydate >= '$togethernow')
OR
(nextgenorder_deliverydate2 >= '$togethernow')
GROUP BY nextgenorder_deliverydate
";